# Notification Mechanism Using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have currently two wars files in which one war has to send notification to other war file using spring.Both of the wars are implemented using spring and web service.
 My requirement is first war has to send notifications to other war file.
Could you please provide some pointers to implement the same using spring ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly your requirements but I'd suggest you to use RestFull web service for this notification. Spring has a perfect support of this kind of services.

Internally the first application will send HTTP POST (or GET) request like http://thehost/webapp2/mynotification

Other way is to communicate using JMS. This way is good if you have to make the communication asynchronous. Spring supports JMS using JMS templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- JMS
- a webservice (or spring http invoker) in the target app and invoke it from the notifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RMI** to export your beans and make them visible from other modules, **better than other alternatives** in this case because:

- JMS is asynchronous and needs a middleware.
- Webservice are less efficient (since it is mostly conceived to communicate heterogeneous platforms).

Take a look here on how to do it:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-rmi

But I would first of all review the architecture you are using, in case you can refactor it for a better integration of business logic.

Comment: no, please not RMI. Also, give links to up-to-date documentation. Spring 2.0 is rather old.

Comment: Which alternative is better than RMI in this case and why? Spring 2.0 is supported so far, and the OP doesn't give any clue about the version he is using.

Comment: spring 2.0 is supported, but is obsolete - always give the newest stable version (thus your answer will be valid for a longer period). As for the question - I would prefer spring Http Invoker. RMI is an 'old' and sometimes cumbersome technology.

Comment: Java is an older technology and it doesn't make it bad :)
HTTP invoker is inefficient because of the protocol it uses. From my point of view, RMI is perfect match when you are communicating Java with Java. No sense to do it vie Webservices, unless you are planning to expand to heterogeneous platforms. I updated the link, thanks!